# Updating Remote Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, remote-server

I am attempting to implement a wave of updates to a remote server. Here is the query I am using:

```
  update openquery(portal_mysql2, 'select * from memberstest_SL')
  set fte_actual=  (select [Full-time_enrollment]
                    FROM [BIDEV].[dbo].[TBL_IPEDS_HISTORY_NEW]
                    inner join openquery(Portal_mysql2, ' select * from memberstest_SL') on cast(unitid as varchar) = Right(nces_agencyid, 6) 
                    where [year] = Year(GetDate())-2 
                      and [Full-time_enrollment] <> '0' 
                      and [Full-time_enrollment] is not null 
                      and cast(unitid as varchar) = Right(nces_agencyid, 6)
                    )
```

This is returning the error:

> subquery returned more than one value

Which makes sense, because I'm trying to update multiple records with their corresponding values in the source table.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: About the error: Try to use `select TOP 1 [Full-time_enrollment]` in your subquery. If you not get the desired result then you should change the logic of update

Comment: using top(1) will replace everything in the query with that first value; this isnt what im looking to do

Comment: Ok, then you should to more explan what do you want. Try to use UPDATE SELECT statement

Comment: Im trying to update every "ftp_actual" entry in the remote server with its corresponding entry in the subquery,

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use something like that:

```
update qe
set    fte_actual = Full-time_enrollment
from   openquery(portal_mysql2, 'select * from memberstest_SL') qe
       inner join [BIDEV].[dbo].[TBL_IPEDS_HISTORY_NEW] tab on CAST(unitid as varchar) = RIGHT(nces_agencyid, 6) 
where year = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2 
 and  ISNULL(Full-time_enrollment, '0') != '0'  
 and  CAST(unitid as varchar) = RIGHT(nces_agencyid, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. This does make plenty of sense, but it nets me this error message:

The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "portal_mysql2" could not UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]". The rowset was using optimistic concurrency and the value of a column has been changed after the containing row was last fetched or resynchronized.